# How can I access web.config settings from an IIS 7 native module?

Tags: c++, iis, iis-7, web-config

I have a native (c++) module registered in IIS 7 that is working correctly, but I'd like to be able to access settings defined in each application's web.config file.

Is it possible to determine which application/virtual directory will handle the request and get its web.config file?

Comment: Same problem here. I know how to access AppHost-Config using native API. Is it even possible to access the App-Config (web.config) using a native API call?